# How checking $(-1)^n$ for $H=H_{n+m}$ is equivalent to checking $(-1)^{m+1}$ for $H_{2m+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

This is from "Mathematics from Economists" by Simon and Blume:

> To determine the definiteness of a quadratic form of $n$ variables, $Q(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x},$ when restricted to a constraint set given by $m$ linear equations $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, construct the $(n+m)\times(n+m)$ symmetric matrix $H$ by bordering the matrix $A$ above and to the left by the coefficients $B$ of the linear constraints: $$H=
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         \mathbf{0} & B \\
>         B^T & A \\
>         \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>   If ${\det H}$ has the same sign as $(-1)^n$ and if the last $n-m$ leading principal minors *alternate* in sign, then $Q$ is a *negative definite* on the constraint set $B\mathbf x=\mathbf{0}$.
>
> Some presentations focus instead on the smallest of the last $n-m$ leading principal submatrices: $H_{2m+1}$, the $2m+1$th order leading pricipal submatrix: To verify negative definiteness, check that $\det H_{2m+1}$ has the sign of $(-1)^{m+1}$ and that the leading pricipal minors of larger order alternate in signs.

Please let me know how checking $(-1)^n$ for $H=H_{n+m}$ is equivalent to checking $(-1)^{m+1}$ for $H_{2m+1}$?

Comment: Where is $(-1)^{2m+1}$ in your citation? Also, notice that $(-1)^{2m+1}=-1$, whatever the integer $m$.

Comment: @arbautjc, sir, Please let me know how checking $(-1)^n$ for $H_{n+m}$ is equivalent to checking $(-1)^{m+1}$ for $H_{2m+1}$?

Comment: @arbautjc, Sir, what do you ask for by saying "Where is $(-1)^{2m+1}$ in your citation?"

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand. You wrote initially *"Shouldn't it be $2m+1$ instead of $m+1$"*, I thought you were talking about the $m+1$ in (-1)^{m+1}. Did I read it incorrectly?

Comment: @arbautjc, sorry for my "misbehave",you are true. Actually I wanted to ask "Please let me know how checking $(-1)^n$ for $H=H_{n+m}$ is equivalent to checking $(-1)^{m+1}$ for $H_{2m+1}$?", but as I am not a native English speaker, I posted "Shouldn't it be 2m+1 instead of m+1" and when I got the unexpected reply from you, I got to know that my question is bad. And I asked my sister for help with English and now i think my question is precise.I will be obliged if you pardon me (and my English skills,too) and answer me.